# Blazor css file not updating when app is launched

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was adding some custom CSS from bootstraps website into my app.css file in Blazor however, while the file is edited in visual studio and saved. When the app launches and loads app.css it loads the older version of app.css without my changes. Would anyone know why this would be occurring? Thanks in advance

### Edited CSS file

```
// ... some more css above....

.b-example-divider {
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-width: 1px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), inset 0 0.125em 0.5em rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75rem;
    top: 0.5rem;
}
```

### Application load app.css

Missing `.b-example-divider` and just loading the document as it was before my change
[image]

Comment: Have you tried CTRL-F5 with the developers tools open?

Comment: @BrianParker Doing this got the app.css to show correctly. What did this do and do I have to do this everytime?

Comment: It clears the cache. CSS is only dynamic in dev. I would not stress to much about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are not seeing changes that you have applied to the app.css file, you may need to clear your browser cache, manually.

A better solution is to use versioning as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css?version=0.1">
```

Add a version number as a query parameter. This will force the browser to look for the latest version of the style sheet ...

Comment: adding version fixed for me!  You're a life-saver!

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I publish my Blazor WASM app to Azure Web Apps. The app still renders an old css until I hard-refresh it. I tried this solution as well as <HeadContent> in App.razor. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers cache files.  Where and how have you declared a link to this file?

Comment: It's the default app.cs file which is linked to the project template. Linked in ```index.html``` as `<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />` not sure how ```index.razor``` would get access

Comment: Are you using an older version of Blazor?  I'm using 6.0, and it (1) doesn't have an app.css file; (2) any changes made to .css are immediately hotloaded.  As for the non auto-renewal, that's by design: the browser caches the file so it doesn't automatically reload every single time a user goes back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I append the Filedate of the Assembly to the css-Files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css?v=@Version" />
```

And keep the version static, because it will not change until next deploy:

```
private static long? version;
public static long Version
{
    get
      {
          version ??= GetAssemblyFileDate();
          return (long)version;
      }
}
private static long GetAssemblyFileDate()
{
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      FileInfo fi = new(assembly.Location);
      return fi.LastWriteTime.Ticks;
  }
```